# Why is Object.get('key') undefined in Ember?

Tags: javascript, object, ember.js, getter

[image: javascript]

So even if I define the keys and values using `.set()` I'm still getting object.get('key') is undefined. There is one example in the image above.

`pojso.set({foo : 'bar'})`
i still get
`pojso.get('foo') is undefined`

it would make sense that if you `set()` something, you would be able to `get()` it, but, this is really weird.

Here are my unit test that kept failing with `undefined` error, I did google many times, It's not like i didn't do any research. I didn't know what to search for. The error messages I'm getting were vague, made me think my object structure wasn't right, or my syntax was wrong.

> ```
> it 'renders', ->
>   component = @subject()
>   # component.set('row', { #undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.get('row.schedules').reduce')
>   #   'schedules' : {}
>   # })
>   # component.set('row', { #undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'schedule.get('timeRanges')')
>   #   'schedules' : [{
>   #     timeRanges : [
>   #       ['on': '0 0 * * 0', 'off': '1 1 * * 1'],
>   #       ['on': '2 2 * * 2', 'off': '3 3 * * 3']
>   #     ]
>   #   }]
>   # })
>   component.set('row', { #undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'schedule.get('timeRanges')')
>     'schedules' : [
>       {
>         'timeRanges' : [
>           {'on': '0 0 * * 0', 'onFrequency': 'Auto'},
>           {'on': '1 1 * * 1', 'onFrequency': 'weekly'}
>         ]
>       },
>       {
>         'timeRanges' : [
>           {'on': '2 2 * * 2', 'onFrequency': 'monthly'},
>           {'on': '3 3 * * 3', 'onFrequency': 'daily'}
>         ]
>       },
>     ]
>   })
>   # console.log('row.schedules.firstObject.timeRanges', component.get('row.schedules.firstObject.timeRanges'))
>   # component.set('row', { # Type error reduce@[native code]
>   #   'schedules' : [
>   #     ['on': '0 0 * * 0', 'off': '1 1 * * 1'],
>   #     ['on': '2 2 * * 2', 'off': '3 3 * * 3']
>   #   ]
>   # })
>   # component.set('row', { #undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'schedule.get('timeRanges')')
>   #   'schedules' : [
>   #     {'on': '0 0 * * 0', 'off': '1 1 * * 1'},
>   #     {'on': '2 2 * * 2', 'off': '3 3 * * 3'}
>   #   ]
>   # })
>   # component.set('row', { #undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.get('row.schedules').reduce')
>   #   'schedules' : {
>   #     'timeRanges' : [
>   #       {'on': '0 0 * * 0', 'off': '1 1 * * 1'},
>   #       {'on': '2 2 * * 2', 'off': '3 3 * * 3'}
>   #   ]}
>   # })
>   # component.set('row', { #undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.get('row.schedules').reduce')
>   #   schedules : {timeRanges : {}}
>   # })
>   # component.set('row', { #undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'this.get('row.schedules').reduce')
>   #   schedules : {}
>   # })
>   # component.set('row': {})
>   # component.set('schedules', {#Assertion Failed: The key provided to set must be a string, you passed [object Object]
>   #   'timeRanges' : {}
>   # })
>   # component.set('row.schedules', {#Assertion Failed: The key provided to set must be a string, you passed [object Object]
>   #   'timeRanges' : [
>   #     {'on': '0 0 * * 0', 'off': '1 1 * * 1'},
>   #     {'on': '2 2 * * 2', 'off': '3 3 * * 3'}
>   #   ]
>   # })
>   # component.set('row.schedules', {#Assertion Failed: The key provided to set must be a string, you passed [object Object]
>   #   'timeRanges' : [
>   #     {on: '0 0 * * 0', off: '1 1 * * 1'},
>   #     {on: '2 2 * * 2', off: '3 3 * * 3'}
>   #   ]
>   # })
>   # component.get('row').set('schedules', {#Assertion Failed: The key provided to set must be a string, you passed [object Object]
>   #   timeRanges : [
>   #     {on: '0 0 * * 0', off: '1 1 * * 1'},
>   #     {on: '2 2 * * 2', off: '3 3 * * 3'}
>   #   ]
>   # })
>   # component.set('row.schedules', {#Assertion Failed: The key provided to set must be a string, you passed [object Object]
>   #   timeRanges : [
>   #     {on: '0 0 * * 0', off: '1 1 * * 1'},
>   #     {on: '2 2 * * 2', off: '3 3 * * 3'}
>   #   ]
>   # })
>   @render()
>   expect(component).to.be.ok
>   expect(@$()).to.have.length(1)
> ```

Comment: That's because JS objects have no function `.get`... you have to create an Ember object which is totally different with different functions

Comment: @Awesome_girl Andrew made a valid point that JS Objects dont have a `get` function. Maybe he doesnt not a solution but he knows the reason why your code is failing. It makes more sense to put that as a comment. Calm down.....

Comment: @Stewartside and AndrewLi, please explain why you are voting my question down.

Comment: I'm sorry if I came off as rude, I did not mean that. My point is that research would've gotten this quite quickly. It's not that the question isn't useful and nobody will learn from it, it just shows a bit less research effort and knowledge of JS.

Comment: @Awesome_girl I havent actually downvoted your answer or question, you can check my rep against last nights leaderboard and what I have made today to see I havent gotten a -1 due to downvoting. It seems you have found your solution and good work on posting it. Dont assume the worst when others dont agree

Comment: @Awesome_girl With a simple search of the Ember or MDN documentations, it would have been clear that Ember objects and JavaScript objects are completely different.

Comment: @AndrewLi , I didn't that the problem was with Ember vs Javascript. I thought my Object structure or syntax was wrong, so I kept searching that. If I knew it was a problem with Ember, I wouldn't even have to search it. Only if you know the answer, it looks so easy to you. I'm new to javascript & ember & coffeescript , new to all of those. Look at how my question if phrased, it doesn't show any knowledge in the difference between ember get() and javascript get().

Comment: @Awesome_girl people probably downvote because the questen has been asket several times, in just slightly diffrent favours. However it seems that theese existing answers are hard to find. Maybe we should consider to change this as a community, but its hard, because you wont get a consistent error message. Also I strongly recommend you to checkout the slack channel. You will usually find nice people pointing you into the right direction, especially if its a beginner question like this.

Comment: @Lux what's the slack channel's name?

Comment: @Awesome_girl its [here](http://emberjs.com/community/). Its `embercommunity`. [Here](https://ember-community-slackin.herokuapp.com/) is the slackin. Feel free to ping me @luxferresum.

Answer (score 2):

Ember objects are different from javascript objects. Instead of `pojso = {foo: 'bar'}`
You should do `Ember.Object.create({foo : 'bar'})`
[image: solution]

source: [Ember docs 'get'](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_get)

source: [Ember.object explanation](http://www.cerebris.com/blog/2012/03/06/understanding-ember-object/)

Comment: Just adding to this: If one *must* use pojo, you can use `Ember.get(pojo, 'attribute.path')` or `Ember.set(pojo, 'attribute.path', value)`